# How to ubuntu(desktop) to ubuntu(beaglebone black- ubuntu arm 13.04) usb communication?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, beagleboard

I want desktop Ubuntu  and Beaglebone (Ubuntu 13.04 for arm ) communicate over USB.

What do I need to do to be recognized as usb device to the  Beagle   in ubuntu desktop pc ?

Can I just make usb device drivers?  or  Can you suggest examples?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use usb2serial or usb2net to connect each other then use standard driver in kernel to communicate.